# How can I troubleshoot a thread in hang in WebSphere Application Server?

Tags: websphere, workload-scheduler

I see there are threads in hang in the websphere application server. How can I troubleshoot this problem? What documentation should I send to the application developer?
Thanks.

Comment: WebSphere provides warnings about hung threads when a thread has been running for longer than a specified time limit. This may and may not be true, sometimes you have a thread that performs a lot of work and exceeds the set time limit. The log output might provide some information about what that particular is up to. Are there no other symptoms of hung threads?

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing is the thread stack - that should show up with the message indicating the hung thread, and it'll tell you what that thread was doing.

That, on its own, might not be enough, particularly if that thread is waiting on some other thread.  In that case, you might need a thread dump.  That can be triggered with "kill -3" against the process ID on non-Windows systems (I'd have to do more research to tell you the equivalent process on Windows, although there are tools that can simulate "kill -3"), and the server also can be configured to do that when it detects a hung thread, using the JVM system property com.ibm.websphere.threadmonitor.dump.java (set to either "true" or an integer value representing the maximum number of thread dumps you want).

The thread dump will go to a file called "javacore...txt" (the "..." will be a long string representing stuff like the timestamp), except on Solaris, where it will go to the server's native_stdout.log.  The javacore has a lot more than just thread stacks, so you can search for "Thread Details" to find that section quickly.  You'll need to search on the thread name/stack from the server log to figure out which thread is the hung one and go from there.

Answer (score -1):

If you are experiencing performance, hang, or high CPU issues with WebSphere Application Server, there is a procedure documented by IBM support team to collect the data necessary to diagnose and resolve the kind of issues. This procedure is based essentially on

- enabling Application Server verboseGC
- running a script, at the time of the problem, which collects 3 javacores for the problematic JVM

At the end of this procedure, you need to collect:

- *.tar.gz file generated by the script
- javacores generated by the script
- server logs (SystemOut.log, native_stderr.log,...)

and send the results to IBM Support.

To get the script and for additional information about this procedure, I suggest to give a look to the following articles:

- [WebSphere MustGather procedure on Linux](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg21115785)
- [WebSphere MustGather procedure on Windows](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21111364)

A similar document exists also for AIX platform.